# Query inside CASE statement with SUM

Tags: sql-server

I have a nestled query I need to use in my `CASE` statement. I need to use the `Max(AgeDate)` that is correctly retrieved in the `SELECT` statement in my `CASE` statement but it does not see my `Max(AgeDate)` in my `SELECT` statement in my `CASE` statement.  Please help...

```
Select 
       Inv.InvoiceNumber,
       Fact_FinInvoice.InvoiceID,
       dbo.Dim_Date.FullDate AS InvoiceDate,
       pra.PracticeName,
       pra.PracticeLogonName,
       pat.AccNo,
       pat.FileNo,
       pmai.MedicalAidNumber,
       per.Title + ' ' + per.Initials + ' ' + per.Surname AS PatientName,
       sch.SCHEMES5,
       sch.SchemeOption,
(SELECT MAX(B.AgeDate) FROM Fact_FinInvoice B WHERE Fact_FinInvoice.InvoiceID = B.InvoiceID AND Fact_FinInvoice.PracticeIdKey = B.PracticeIdKey)  MaxAgeDate,

       SUM(Fact_FinInvoice.Amount) AS Amount,
       SUM(Fact_FinInvoice.AmountFunder) AS AmountFunder,
       SUM(Fact_FinInvoice.AmountPatient) AS AmountPatient,  
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, MaxAgeDate, GETDATE()) between 0 and 29 and AmountFunder != 0 THEN AmountFunder ELSE 0 END) as FunderCurrent,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, MaxAgeDate, GETDATE()) between 30 and 59 and AmountFunder != 0 THEN AmountFunder ELSE 0 END) as Funder30Days, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, MaxAgeDate, GETDATE()) between 60 and 89 and AmountFunder != 0 THEN AmountFunder ELSE 0 END) as Funder60Days,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, MaxAgeDate, GETDATE()) between 90 and 119 and AmountFunder != 0 THEN AmountFunder ELSE 0 END) as Funder90Days,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, MaxAgeDate, GETDATE()) >= 120 and AmountFunder != 0 THEN AmountFunder ELSE 0 END) as Funder120Days, 

       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, MaxAgeDate, GETDATE()) between 0 and 29 and AmountPatient != 0 THEN AmountPatient ELSE 0 END) as PatientCurrent,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, MaxAgeDate, GETDATE()) between 30 and 59 and AmountPatient != 0 THEN AmountPatient ELSE 0 END) as Patient30Days, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, MaxAgeDate, GETDATE()) between 60 and 89 and AmountPatient != 0 THEN AmountPatient ELSE 0 END) as Patient60Days,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, MaxAgeDate, GETDATE()) between 90 and 119 and AmountPatient != 0 THEN AmountPatient ELSE 0 END) as Patient90Days,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, MaxAgeDate, GETDATE()) >= 120 and AmountPatient != 0 THEN AmountPatient ELSE 0 END) as Patient120Days, 

       mcs.Name AS BureauManager,
       mcso.Name AS BureauOfficer
FROM            dbo.Fact_FinInvoice LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.Dim_Practice pra ON dbo.Fact_FinInvoice.PracticeIdKey = pra.PracticeIDCode LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.Fact_Invoice Inv ON dbo.Fact_FinInvoice.InvoiceID = Inv.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.Dim_PersonMAInfo pmai  INNER JOIN
                dbo.Dim_Scheme sch  ON sch.CodeNo = pmai.CodeNo ON Inv.PersonMAInfoCode = pmai.PersonMAInfoID  LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.Dim_BureauStaffProvider bsp  INNER JOIN
                dbo.Dim_MediChargeStaff mcs ON mcs.ID = bsp.BureauStaffId ON bsp.ProviderID = Inv.ProviderId INNER JOIN
                dbo.Dim_MediChargeStaff mcso ON mcs.Manager = mcso.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.Dim_Date ON Inv.InvoiceDateKey = dbo.Dim_Date.DateKey LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.Dim_Patient pat INNER JOIN
                dbo.Dim_PersonData per ON per.PersonDataId = pat.PersonId ON pat.PatientId = Inv.PatientKey



GROUP BY    Inv.InvoiceNumber,
            Fact_FinInvoice.InvoiceID,
            dbo.Dim_Date.FullDate,
            pra.PracticeName,
            pra.PracticeLogonName,
            pmai.MedicalAidNumber,
            sch.SCHEMES5,
            sch.SchemeOption,
            mcs.Name,
            mcso.Name,
            pat.AccNo,
            pat.FileNo,
            per.Title + ' ' + per.Initials + ' ' + per.Surname,
            [Fact_FinInvoice].PracticeIdKey
```

Answer (score 2):

USE CTE on top and then join that CTE with your joins:

```
;with mycte as (
select MAX(AgeDate) as MaxAgeDate,InvoiceID  FROM Fact_FinInvoice 
group by InvoiceID
)

Select 
       Inv.InvoiceNumber,
       Fact_FinInvoice.InvoiceID,
       dbo.Dim_Date.FullDate AS InvoiceDate,
       pra.PracticeName,
       pra.PracticeLogonName,
       pat.AccNo,
       pat.FileNo,
       pmai.MedicalAidNumber,
       per.Title + ' ' + per.Initials + ' ' + per.Surname AS PatientName,
       sch.SCHEMES5,
       sch.SchemeOption,
        MaxAgeDate,
       SUM(Fact_FinInvoice.Amount) AS Amount,
       SUM(Fact_FinInvoice.AmountFunder) AS AmountFunder,
       SUM(Fact_FinInvoice.AmountPatient) AS AmountPatient,  
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, MaxAgeDate, GETDATE()) between 0 and 29 and AmountFunder != 0 THEN AmountFunder ELSE 0 END) as FunderCurrent,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, MaxAgeDate, GETDATE()) between 30 and 59 and AmountFunder != 0 THEN AmountFunder ELSE 0 END) as Funder30Days, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, MaxAgeDate, GETDATE()) between 60 and 89 and AmountFunder != 0 THEN AmountFunder ELSE 0 END) as Funder60Days,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, MaxAgeDate, GETDATE()) between 90 and 119 and AmountFunder != 0 THEN AmountFunder ELSE 0 END) as Funder90Days,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, MaxAgeDate, GETDATE()) >= 120 and AmountFunder != 0 THEN AmountFunder ELSE 0 END) as Funder120Days, 

       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, MaxAgeDate, GETDATE()) between 0 and 29 and AmountPatient != 0 THEN AmountPatient ELSE 0 END) as PatientCurrent,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, MaxAgeDate, GETDATE()) between 30 and 59 and AmountPatient != 0 THEN AmountPatient ELSE 0 END) as Patient30Days, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, MaxAgeDate, GETDATE()) between 60 and 89 and AmountPatient != 0 THEN AmountPatient ELSE 0 END) as Patient60Days,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, MaxAgeDate, GETDATE()) between 90 and 119 and AmountPatient != 0 THEN AmountPatient ELSE 0 END) as Patient90Days,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, MaxAgeDate, GETDATE()) >= 120 and AmountPatient != 0 THEN AmountPatient ELSE 0 END) as Patient120Days, 

       mcs.Name AS BureauManager,
       mcso.Name AS BureauOfficer
FROM            dbo.Fact_FinInvoice LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.Dim_Practice pra ON dbo.Fact_FinInvoice.PracticeIdKey = pra.PracticeIDCode LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.Fact_Invoice Inv ON dbo.Fact_FinInvoice.InvoiceID = Inv.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.Dim_PersonMAInfo pmai  INNER JOIN
                dbo.Dim_Scheme sch  ON sch.CodeNo = pmai.CodeNo ON Inv.PersonMAInfoCode = pmai.PersonMAInfoID  LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.Dim_BureauStaffProvider bsp  INNER JOIN
                dbo.Dim_MediChargeStaff mcs ON mcs.ID = bsp.BureauStaffId ON bsp.ProviderID = Inv.ProviderId INNER JOIN
                dbo.Dim_MediChargeStaff mcso ON mcs.Manager = mcso.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.Dim_Date ON Inv.InvoiceDateKey = dbo.Dim_Date.DateKey LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.Dim_Patient pat INNER JOIN
                dbo.Dim_PersonData per ON per.PersonDataId = pat.PersonId ON pat.PatientId = Inv.PatientKey
                join mycte ct
                on Fact_FinInvoice.InvoiceID = ct.InvoiceID

GROUP BY    Inv.InvoiceNumber,
            Fact_FinInvoice.InvoiceID,
            dbo.Dim_Date.FullDate,
            pra.PracticeName,
            pra.PracticeLogonName,
            pmai.MedicalAidNumber,
            sch.SCHEMES5,
            sch.SchemeOption,
            mcs.Name,
            mcso.Name,
            pat.AccNo,
            pat.FileNo,
            per.Title + ' ' + per.Initials + ' ' + per.Surname,
            [Fact_FinInvoice].PracticeIdKey
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use aliases given in select part in other places in the select, but you can use outer apply to fetch data that you'll then use in select, with something like this:

```
select
    ....
    sch.SchemeOption,
    AD.MaxAgeDate,
    ....
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, AD.MaxAgeDate, GETDATE())
from
    dbo.Fact_FinInvoice
    outer apply (
        SELECT MAX(B.AgeDate) 
        FROM Fact_FinInvoice B 
        WHERE Fact_FinInvoice.InvoiceID = B.InvoiceID AND
        Fact_FinInvoice.PracticeIdKey = B.PracticeIdKey)  AD
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ...
```

And you can also calculate the datediff already in the outer apply as a second column, so you don't have to repeat the same code several times.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cross Apply

```
SELECT          Inv.InvoiceNumber,
                Fact_FinInvoice.InvoiceID,
                dbo.Dim_Date.FullDate                              AS InvoiceDate,
                pra.PracticeName,
                pra.PracticeLogonName,
                pat.AccNo,
                pat.FileNo,
                pmai.MedicalAidNumber,
                per.Title + ' ' + per.Initials + ' ' + per.Surname AS PatientName,
                sch.SCHEMES5,
                sch.SchemeOption,
                cs.MaxAgeDate,
                Sum(Fact_FinInvoice.Amount)                        AS Amount,
                Sum(Fact_FinInvoice.AmountFunder)                  AS AmountFunder,
                Sum(Fact_FinInvoice.AmountPatient)                 AS AmountPatient,
                Sum(CASE
                      WHEN Datediff(dd, MaxAgeDate, Getdate()) BETWEEN 0 AND 29
                           AND AmountFunder != 0 THEN AmountFunder
                      ELSE 0
                    END)                                           AS FunderCurrent,
                Sum(CASE
                      WHEN Datediff(dd, MaxAgeDate, Getdate()) BETWEEN 30 AND 59
                           AND AmountFunder != 0 THEN AmountFunder
                      ELSE 0
                    END)                                           AS Funder30Days,
                Sum(CASE
                      WHEN Datediff(dd, MaxAgeDate, Getdate()) BETWEEN 60 AND 89
                           AND AmountFunder != 0 THEN AmountFunder
                      ELSE 0
                    END)                                           AS Funder60Days,
                Sum(CASE
                      WHEN Datediff(dd, MaxAgeDate, Getdate()) BETWEEN 90 AND 119
                           AND AmountFunder != 0 THEN AmountFunder
                      ELSE 0
                    END)                                           AS Funder90Days,
                Sum(CASE
                      WHEN Datediff(dd, MaxAgeDate, Getdate()) >= 120
                           AND AmountFunder != 0 THEN AmountFunder
                      ELSE 0
                    END)                                           AS Funder120Days,
                Sum(CASE
                      WHEN Datediff(dd, MaxAgeDate, Getdate()) BETWEEN 0 AND 29
                           AND AmountPatient != 0 THEN AmountPatient
                      ELSE 0
                    END)                                           AS PatientCurrent,
                Sum(CASE
                      WHEN Datediff(dd, MaxAgeDate, Getdate()) BETWEEN 30 AND 59
                           AND AmountPatient != 0 THEN AmountPatient
                      ELSE 0
                    END)                                           AS Patient30Days,
                Sum(CASE
                      WHEN Datediff(dd, MaxAgeDate, Getdate()) BETWEEN 60 AND 89
                           AND AmountPatient != 0 THEN AmountPatient
                      ELSE 0
                    END)                                           AS Patient60Days,
                Sum(CASE
                      WHEN Datediff(dd, MaxAgeDate, Getdate()) BETWEEN 90 AND 119
                           AND AmountPatient != 0 THEN AmountPatient
                      ELSE 0
                    END)                                           AS Patient90Days,
                Sum(CASE
                      WHEN Datediff(dd, MaxAgeDate, Getdate()) >= 120
                           AND AmountPatient != 0 THEN AmountPatient
                      ELSE 0
                    END)                                           AS Patient120Days,
                mcs.Name                                           AS BureauManager,
                mcso.Name                                          AS BureauOfficer
FROM            dbo.Fact_FinInvoice FFI
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Dim_Practice pra ON FFI.PracticeIdKey = pra.PracticeIDCode
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Fact_Invoice Inv ON FFI.InvoiceID = Inv.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Dim_PersonMAInfo pmai
                INNER JOIN dbo.Dim_Scheme sch ON sch.CodeNo = pmai.CodeNo ON Inv.PersonMAInfoCode = pmai.PersonMAInfoID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Dim_BureauStaffProvider bsp
                INNER JOIN dbo.Dim_MediChargeStaff mcs ON mcs.ID = bsp.BureauStaffId ON bsp.ProviderID = Inv.ProviderId
INNER JOIN      dbo.Dim_MediChargeStaff mcso ON mcs.Manager = mcso.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Dim_Date ON Inv.InvoiceDateKey = dbo.Dim_Date.DateKey
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Dim_Patient pat
                INNER JOIN dbo.Dim_PersonData per ON per.PersonDataId = pat.PersonId ON pat.PatientId = Inv.PatientKey
CROSS APPLY     (SELECT Max(B.AgeDate) AS MaxAgeDAte
                 FROM   Fact_FinInvoice B
                 WHERE  FFI.InvoiceID = B.InvoiceID
                        AND FFI.PracticeIdKey = B.PracticeIdKey) CS
GROUP           BY Inv.InvoiceNumber,
                   FFI.InvoiceID,
                   dbo.Dim_Date.FullDate,
                   pra.PracticeName,
                   pra.PracticeLogonName,
                   pmai.MedicalAidNumber,
                   sch.SCHEMES5,
                   sch.SchemeOption,
                   mcs.Name,
                   mcso.Name,
                   pat.AccNo,
                   pat.FileNo,
                   per.Title + ' ' + per.Initials + ' ' + per.Surname,
                   [FFI].PracticeIdKey
```